# Dynamically create leaflet popup via JavaScript Object

Tags: leaflet, javascript, jquery, dynamic

I want to dynamically populate a marker popup via a JavaScript object.

I have a JavaScript object like so:

```
{address: "92101 S Martin Ave.", address2: "", agent_name: "mr smith", 
animal: "sheep", car: "honda", city: "Chicago", county: "Cook County", ID: "1", 
latitude: "41.718986", longitude: "-87.550646", postalcode: "60617", 
stateProvince: "IL", status: "GS"}
```

I want to be able to loop thru all of properties within the object and display those within the popup.

I have tried the below:

```
for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(data).length; j++) {
                var marker = L.marker([data[j].latitude, data[j].longitude]).addTo(markers);
                marker.bindPopup(data[j]);
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var yourData = getInfoFrom(yourObject).join(" <br>");

L.marker([63.43, 10.395]).addTo(map)
.bindPopup(yourData)
.openPopup();

function getInfoFrom(object) {
  var popupFood = [];
  for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var stringLine = "The " + key + " is " + object[key];
      popupFood.push(stringLine);
    }
  }
  return popupFood;
}
```

[image: Example popup with info from object properties]

```
var yourObject = {
  address: "92101 S Martin Ave.",
  address2: "",
  agent_name: "mr smith",
  animal: "sheep",
  car: "honda",
  city: "Chicago",
  county: "Cook County",
  ID: "1",
  latitude: "41.718986",
  longitude: "-87.550646",
  postalcode: "60617",
  stateProvince: "IL",
  status: "GS"
};
```